# mysqli Retrieving user_id with hashed pass using prepared statement

Tags: mysqli, hash, passwords

I want to get a user_id from a table by searching for a hashed password using mysqli prepare statement.

I know how a prepared statement works eg

```
$query = "SELECT `colour` FROM `pallet`";
$query.=" Where `colour`=? "
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',$colour="blue");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($colour);
    while($stmt->fetch())
snip
```

So I have no problem with prepared statements but the problem is this to match my hashed password, I have to take the entered password

```
$input_password = crypt($password,$database_pass);
```

and hash it before I match. So I thought I would try something like this

```
$query = "SELECT `password` FROM `log`";
$query.=" Where `password`=? "
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('s',crypt($password,$database_pass));
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($colour);
```

Obviously this doesn't work, as I need to get $database_pass from the database before I bind it. I am trying to do it all in one go.

Before this I wasn't using a prepared table, and I was just getting the passwords and checking them afterwards in a loop, but I am hoping to improve this by doing it all in one go if possible.

I always solve something one way, and then later try to improve it, but I am having difficulty with this one.

Ok I have managed to do it a different way, but the problem with my new code is that it has to read the whole table before it can compare. I would rather do it with a where clause because then it only gets the data it needs.

```
       Global $db;
        $query = "SELECT `temp_pass`,`user_id` FROM `".$database."`.`logon`";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($temp_pass,$user_id);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
$input_password = crypt($password,$temp_pass);  
            if($input_password == $temp_pass):
                return $user_id;
                break;
            endif;
        }
```

Comment: Why not just fetch database_pass and then compare?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. It isn't just one database pass. crypt use the pass in the database to hash. so the hashed password is in the database. My old method would be to bring all the lines with a msqli fetch and then loop through to find the password, but I am trying to do it with less code. When a user enters a password it has to be hashed with the password in the database so I can perform a match.

Comment: I am thinking an inner select might be the answer. Just gotta work it out

Comment: May be you should select a row based not on the password but by some other field. What about login?

Comment: This is for a password reset. So the infomation is encrypted in an email coming back to the webpage. Yes I can encrypt the id in the email, and that is how I originally had it, but I decided it is safer if I don't put the id in the email link encrypted or not. So now I just want to do it with the pass coming back instead to make the site more secure.

Comment: What if there will be two users with the same password?

Comment: This is a tempory password used to reset the password.

Comment: try to make it less complicated

Comment: Due to time constraints I have had to go back to my old method of sending the id and using that to add the new password. It is encrypted and padded so it is pretty safe. When I have more time I will improve the system though

Comment: To stick with id is a very good idea. I'd suggest to keep with it, without trying to "improve" the current approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot search for properly salted passwords in a database, the problem is just what you discribed: to calculate a comparable password hash, you would need to get the salt first, which you can't because you cannot find the hash.

This applies to password hashes, it is another thing if you have strong tokens for password resets though. If the tokens are strong enough, you can store an unsalted hash (e.g. SHA-256), and those you can find in your database.

Comment: I have decided to do it this way. The password expires in 15minutes anyway which minimises somebody hacking the key which they wouldn't know anyway.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - Ok, with strong tokens I meant at least 20 characters 0-9 a-z A-Z, those do not need salting.